# Everything is install but in Android Studio Flutter and Dart Error

Tags: flutter, dart

I installed everything but when I run flutter doctor then this error occurs.

Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.5.1, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.2)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.1)
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[!] Connected devices
    ! No devices available
```

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.

Answer (score 1):

you can ignore those errors if you are going to use vscode as your IDE.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this error is:

```
flutter channel dev
flutter upgrade
flutter config --android-studio-dir="C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio"
flutter doctor -v
```

when I run these 4 commands then this error will automatically solve.